# ADFS 2.0 and User Creation

Tags: asp.net, adfs2.0

I would like to Know about the user Creation Process in ADFS. As from the link below i came to know we cant create Users with ADFS .

[Is it possible to create a new user via ADFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520252/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-user-via-adfs)

Then how we can Create a User for eg in case of Internet Scenoria. I would like to know the proven practices for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of Identity Manager that provisions users into AD. As per the link above, you can add a link to the ADFS login page to provide this capability as well as any self-service functionality that you require.

In terms of provisioning into AD, see

- [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)
- [Everything in Active Directory via C#.Net 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/)

Answer (score 0):

In a practice approach ADFS it is used as follows:

1 The user logs into their local PC (as they typically would when commencing work in the morning)

2 The user needs to obtain information on a partner company's extranet website - for example to obtain pricing or product details

3 The user navigates to the partner company extranet site - for example: http://example.com

4 The partner website now does not require any password to be typed in - instead, the user credentials are passed to the partner extranet site using AD FS

5 The user is now logged into the partner website and can interact with the website 'logged in' AD FS integrates with Active Directory Domain Services, **using it as an identity provider**. AD FS can interact with other WS-* and SAML 2.0 compliant federation services as federation partners.

You can create users into the domain in multiple ways